# NG1: Class controller constructor vs $onInit for variable initialization and method bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ecmascript-6, angular1.6

before marking this question as a duplicate...I know what you are thinking, this has been asked countless times, but not exactly.

I know from various sources during my research (including official docs, and Angular Guru's and evangelists) that the `$onInit` block is commonly reserved for **initialization work/logic that relies on angular having finished all of it's bindings**.

However, variable initialization does not really fit this "work/logic" definition. Specially variables which don't have any angular logic in them. For that reason, the ES6 constructor seems to be a better fit for variable initialization. Same goes for method bindings that require lexicaly bound scope for callbacks like so:

```
class myController() {
  constructor() {
    this.myVariableOne = 1,
    this.myVariableTwo = 2,
    this.myVariableThree = 3;

    this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this);
  }

  $onInit() { }

  myMethod() {
    console.log(this.myVariableOne, this.myVariableTwo, this.myVariableThree);
  }
}
```

And while this looks good at following "the angular way" of doings things as far as only using the `$onInit` block for initialization work/logic, I've also seen plenty of people that say that angular controller class constructors **should only be used for Dependency Injection setup**.

So, this has me confused. The constructor seems to be the best suited block for variable initialization and method bindings, and `$onInit` seems like it doesn't really fit that role, but it really isn't clear what I should use then. Can someone please help me figure out where I should be placing my variable definition and method bindings?

Comment: In the code above there are no this.myVariableOne, etc.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This totally depends on what are these properties. For initial static values (like in the code above) a constructor is the proper place.

`$onInit` is intended for DOM and data binding initialization code, it is a direct counterpart of pre-1.5 pre-link function. Other initialization code can be placed for testability reasons in `$onInit`, too.

Considering that there is some instance (not prototype) method that is called on initialization:

```
constructor() {
  this.method = () => ...;
}

$onInit() {
  this.method();
}
```

It can be tested like

```
const ctrl = $controller('...');
spyOn(ctrl, 'method').and...;
ctrl.$onInit();
expect(ctrl.method).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

It wouldn't be possible to spy or mock it if it were called in constructor.

This concern affects non-modular ES5 apps to a greater degree, because their methods are usually defined as `this.method = ...`, and controller `prototype` can't be easily reached because there's no way to import controller constructor.

Comment: Thank your input! I agree that `$onInit` is often used for binding initialization code, however, binding in what context? Because I know it's used for binding code which relies on angular bindings. However, scope bindings with `.bind()` sound more like part of non-angular initialization that looks better in the controller constructor.

Comment: I've added a clarification. $onInit is for *data* binding. `this.myMethod.bind(this)` absolutely belongs to a constructor. The earlier it's done, the better.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your general assessment. I keep my constructors pretty light, but if I am doing things at instantiation that aren't really angular related, I've been putting them into the constructor. I haven't had any issues with them. I just looked at a dozen or so of them and I am basically not doing anything but initializing properties and assigning dependency injections to properties. I only have one controller where it calls any external code at all.

Writing about angular 1.5 is very sparse. If you haven't already seen this: https://toddmotto.com/rewriting-angular-styleguide-angular-2 I think it's the best style guide out there for "modern angularjs."

Comment: Thanks! Also, I'm already a Todd Motto and John Papa follower, but John Papa's use of classes in Angular 1 is very limited, while Todd Motto proposed that `$onInit` should be used for everything, including variable initialization. However, this bloats the `$onInit` and after reading a lot into what it was made for (not from the ng-docs, since as you say they are incredibly sparse), it doesn't seem like a good fit. But thanks for your input!

Comment: @sgarcia.dev Todd Motto is a nice dev, but he got it wrong here. This contradicts other concerns. I.e. it's natural to define props as class and constructor in TypeScript (in A1, too), but in this case they will be initialized in constructor.

Comment: @sgarcia.dev I've been in the habit of deferring what I can from OnInit to postLink in order to keep my onInit's as light as possible.